# Tensorflow 2.x: List behavior of model architecture / select model parts via indices like in Pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0

Is it possible to imitate the pytorch behaviour of selecting parts of an existing model using list indices (for transfer learning) in TF 2.x?

Example:

In pytorch I can take the first seven layers or a mobilenet v2 architecture and use them as backbone for my custom architecture like this:

```
class MyCustomNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(MyCustomNetwork, self).__init__()
        model_mobilenetv2 = mobilenet_v2(pretrained=True, cpu_mode=cpu_mode)

        # Take output features after layer 7 
        self.model_until_layer7 = model_mobilenetv2.features[:7]
        self.some_custom_layers = [...]


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.model_until_layer7(x)
        x = self.some_custom_layers(x)
        return x
```

I know the TF [transfer learning example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning) but it only allows for the head of mobilenet_v2 and not the cutting after arbitrary layers